# How to include a header with the data that i send to a tcp server

Tags: c#, tcpclient, tcp

I hope this is a good day to get a good answer. I have code that sends data to a TCP server. Am ok on sending the data but i do not know how to include the header. guidelines of how the header should be like are as follows

> Communication between the Device and the XML interface uses a TCP message  beginning with a header to indicate the length of the data segment of the message. This header must precede all messages sent to the XML interface, and will be sent at the beginning of all TCP responses from the XML interface.
>
> If the message length is less than 2^16-1 or 65535 then a two-byte header will be used.
>
> The first byte of the header contains the quotient of the length of the message (excluding this header) and 256. The second byte contains the remainder of this division. Both these values are represented in binary as unsigned integer values ranging from 0 to 255 (bytes 0x00 to 0xFF).
>
> If the message length is greater than or equal to 216-1 or 65535 bytes then a six-byte header will be used.
>
> In this case the bytes 0xFF 0xFF should be sent followed by a four-byte length indicator, i.e. six bytes in total.

Now what i have is as follows and and as you can see it doesn't address the header issue. Which is basically my question.

```
    private static void main2(String hostname, int port, String message)
    {

        String response = String.Empty;            
       TcpClient client = new TcpClient(hostname, port);  
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream,Encoding.UTF8);

        writer.AutoFlush = false;            
        writer.WriteLine(message);          
        writer.Flush();           
        writer.Close();          
        
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
        response = reader.ReadLine();

        stream.Close();
    }
```

Information does get to my TCP Server. (confirmed by using tcp viewer). But because i don't know how to include the header there is no way that the server can respond back to me as it is considering my request as not complete. Thanks in advance guys for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Header they are talking about is not only a prefix of the message?  They don't provide example?  Try this (let's say message is less than 65535 bytes) :

```
var totalMessageLength = message.Length + 2;
var quotient = (int)totalMessageLength / 256;
var modulo = totalMessageLength % 256;
message = $"{quotient.ToString("X2")}{modulo.ToString("X2")}{message}";
```

Comment: Unfortunately the don't really provide an example.The only clue that i have is from looking at TCP viewer where a predefined demo test (no code available) message with 306 bytes produces this header ".0".(dot zero)

Comment: Also the above solution didnt work. Also why add the + 2?

Comment: Since we had no clue, I just tried to add 2 characters before the message, which is the header.  TCP seem for me a raw message.

Comment: Can you post the demo message with .0 header?  You can post in HEX.

Comment: Using TCP viewer i posted the demo message that was coming out. as ascii,, utf-8 and HEX. i got no response from the TCP server. Also noticed that the XML i see when i run the demo is not entirely the same as the one that the demo says it has sent.  .0<?xml version=
0010  22 31 2E 30 22 20 65 6E  63 6F 64 69 6E 67 3D 22  "1.0" encoding="
0020  55 54 46 2D 38 22 3F 3E  0D 0A 3C 45 73 70 3A 49  UTF-8"?>..<Esp the two dots between utf-8"?> and <ESP are not part of the test message with .0 header

Comment: Can you post it only in HEX?  This is very hard to read when it is mixed.

Comment: I think we need BW 's help.  [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37732201/postilion-esocket-pos-structured-xml-data-tags.) because am trying to accomplish what he has accomplished. How do we invite him to the discussion?

Comment: I don't know how to invite him.  This appear to be very different.  He doesn't talk about a TCP header at all.